# Removing users from multiple groups

Tags: powershell, active-directory, usergroups, multiple-users

I'm trying to clean up our Active Directory system at work and what would help us out is the automation of users being assigned to the correct groups.

I work at a school district and every new employee we get they are automatically put into a group according to what school they will be working at, this is done using the `Department` attribute.

The original code that was built only assigned new employees to these building groups, but if an employee changed their location they wouldn't be removed from their originally assigned group. This is the solution I've been working on for this, but I simply cannot get it to take multiple inputs at 1 time.

```
$EveryoneUsers = Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties UserPrincipalName
$EveryoneUsers = $EveryoneUsers | Where { ($_.UserPrincipalName -notlike '131*') }
$EveryoneUsers = $EveryoneUsers | Where { ($_.UserPrincipalName -notlike '$null') }
$EveryoneUsers = $EveryoneUsers | Where { ($_.DistinguishedName -like '*OU=Staff*' ) }
$EveryoneUsers = $EveryoneUsers | Select sAMAccountName

$EveryoneGroups = @('Iowa Everyone', 'South Everyone', 'Centennial Everyone', 'Union Everyone', 'East Valley Everyone', 'West Everyone', 'New Horizons Everyone', 'Columbia Everyone', 
                    'Gateways Everyone', 'Nampa High Everyone', 'Snake River Everyone', 'Park Ridge Everyone', 'Skyview Everyone', 'District Office Everyone', 'Roosevelt Everyone', 
                    'Central Everyone', 'Greenhurst Everyone', 'Nampa Early Childhood Everyone' ,'Owyhee Everyone', 'District Operations Everyone', 'TVLA Everyone', 'Endeavor Everyone', 
                    'Lake Ridge Everyone', 'Willow Creek Everyone', 'Reagan Everyone', 'Lone Star Everyone', 'Sherman Everyone'); 

ForEach ($EveryoneGroup in $EveryoneGroups) {Remove-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $EveryoneUsers -MemberOf $EveryoneGroup -Confirm:$false}
```

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, you can add a 2nd `ForEach` loop for all the users, `foreach ($user in $allUser) { foreach ($group in $allGroups) { Remove-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $user -MemberOf $group } }`

Comment: I had no idea you could add a foreach loop inside a foreach loop. This helps, but I'm still getting an error.
`ForEach ($EveryoneUser in $EveryoneUsers) {ForEach ($EveryoneGroup in $EveryoneGroups) {Remove-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $EveryoneUser -MemberOf $EveryoneGroup -Confirm:$false -WhatIf}}`
It gives a new error now.

Remove-ADPrincipalGroupMembership : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Most likely your `$EveryoneUser` variable is set as a `PSCustomObject`, you can input only the `SamAccountName` property into the cmdlet like `Remove-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $EveryoneUser.SamAccountName`

Comment: You’re calling ```Get-ADUser … -Properties UserPrincipalName``` but then in later lines you’re also trying to reference ```DistinguishedName``` and ```samAccountName``` - I can’t test right now whether ```Get-ADUser``` populates these additional fields anyway even if they’re not in the ```-Properties``` list, but if it *doesn’t* then you need to add them to it…

Comment: Good catch on that, it does already pull that attribute. I guess I had it in there because I was referencing it right away and I was on auto-pilot a bit while doing that. I'm still running into an issue with the script, but I think that it has more with how its being inserted into my existing script than anything else. When I performed just this last bit on my local system using `-WhatIf` it went off without a hitch, now for some tuning.